# Subtract 1 day from first day of the year not working as expected

Tags: php, datetime

Hi i am trying to subtract 1 day and 1 year from first day of the year using php

**Code**

```
        var_dump(date('Y-01-01', strtotime('-1 day')));
        var_dump(date('Y-01-01', strtotime('-1 year')));
```

**Result**

`string(10) "2019-01-01"`
`string(10) "2018-01-01"`

I expect the first result to be `2018-12-31` instead of `2019-01-01` , why only `-1 year` is working correctly ? please help . thanks in advance.

Comment: you use the original date for the 2nd calculation, not the date returned by the first calculation

Comment: It's because you're using `date('Y-01-01'` instead of `date('Y-m-d'`

Comment: @Nick i want the first day of the year

Comment: You said you wanted the first result to be `'2018-12-31'`

Comment: @ 2019-01-01 - 1 day = 2018-12-31

Comment: Yes but it won't display as `2018-12-31` if you use a format of `Y-01-01`

Comment: @Nick so why date('Y-01-01', strtotime('-1 year')) is correctly display 2018-01-01 ? and please help me to find the answer

Comment: For your above comment @KanishkaPanamaldeniya timezone issue maybe? I get back `string(10) "2019-01-15" string(10) "2018-01-16"` if that's what it should be.

Comment: @user3783243 it is giving me 2018-01-01

Comment: @Funk Forty Nine  Thanks  i wlll check that :)

Comment: @user3783243 please read the question carefully :)

Comment: welcome @KanishkaPanamaldeniya My local machine is set at `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` inside a php file, and not in the `.ini` file(s), which could also be edited in order to use the correct timezone, again... if that is the issue at hand, or part of it.

Comment: What @Nick posted in an answer below, seems to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually subtracting a day or a year from the beginning of the year, you are subtracting them from the current date. Also, because you are outputting using `Y-01-01` format, both dates will always have 1 for the month and day. You need to first generate the first day of the year and then subtract from that and output using `Y-m-d` format:

```
$foy = strtotime(date('Y-01-01'));
var_dump(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', $foy)));
var_dump(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year', $foy)));
```

Output:

```
string(10) "2018-12-31" 
string(10) "2018-01-01"
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2plqf)